# Is override for the user of a class or for the implementer?

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding

This is basically a best practice question, and a question about the intended usage of `override`:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void func();
};

struct B : public A
{
    virtual void func() override;
};
```

In the above case it seems totally reasonable to use `override`. It tells the user of `B` that `func` overrides a virtual function from `A` (information that could only be conveyed with a comment pre-C++11). But what about when the user isn't supposed to perceive that `A` is a base class... like if `A` is `private`ly inherited:

```
struct B : private A
{
    virtual void func() override;
};
```

In this case I'm telling the user of `B` about an internal implementation detail they shouldn't know exists. If the purpose of `override` is to give the writer of `B` an error if he didn't actually override anything, that's fine; But if the purpose is to convey more information to the user, should I *not* write `override` in this case?

Comment: `override` will yield a compiler error if you override the wrong signature; i.e., it helps enforce correctness. Use it. Always. (Plus, what on earth could be the use of a virtual function in a class you inherit from privately? If that's the only use-case you're asking about, I'd say it's dubious.)

Comment: If you really wanted to hide the fact, you could use a macro to cover it up, but that's a whole new choice.

Comment: @ildjarn: so what happens if a private base class calls a function that is overridden in the derived class?

Comment: @Steve : Is that actually something people do? I mean, given the existence of CRTP...

Comment: Shrug. It's reasonable for a base class to call virtual functions, and I think it's probably reasonable for a derived class to use private bases without the base class needing to know or care that the inheritance happens to be private. So think I can see how you might get there, if there's a base class that does the job you need. You're not necessarily going to rewrite it as a CRTP class as a special case for use when the inheritance is private.

Comment: `struct B : private A` is already leaking implementation details.

Comment: @larsmans True. Maybe someday the language will let you expose *only* what's relevant to users.

Comment: I doubt it. That would require a major overhaul in the language, and I don't see how it could be done in the "no-overhead" style that C++ is designed for. (Though I could imagine stronger language or library support for the Pimpl idiom.)

Comment: I do not even understand the problem here; what about: struct B : public A { virtual void func(); //override: A::func() }; Does the comment leak an implementation detail?

Comment: "_If you can't have a reference or pointer to the base_" The members of the derived classes can. The user cannot - this is the whole point of private inheritance.

Comment: @curiousguy In order for your 3 comments: 1) No it's not, private inheritance is private. By definition the user doesn't have access to what it provides. It's entirely an implementation detail and it would be nice if the user didn't know it happened (I guess you could pImpl) 2) No it doesn't (if the inheritance is known to the user they may also care if the virtual is overridden or not). 3) We all know what private inheritance is, what's your point?

Comment: @Dave "_It's entirely an implementation detail_" Incorrect. It's relevant for classes derived from B. "_they may also care if the virtual is overridden or not)._" Why? The inheritance is non-virtual.

Comment: @Dave "_This seems to be a question, not an answer._" It was an answer, not a question. Just because it ends with "?" does not mean it is not an answer. How many times do I have to repeat that? Is the reader expected to be that unintelligent?

Comment: @curiousguy `protected` inheritance would be relevant to classes derived from B. `private` inheritance is not. Maybe you have to keep repeating it because you keep writing answers which don't answer anything, question mark or not.

Comment: @Dave "_protected inheritance would be relevant to classes derived from B. private inheritance is not._" Sorry, this is not correct. "_Maybe you have to keep repeating it because you keep writing answers which don't answer anything, question mark or not._" A comment does not break encapsulation, and neither does the `override` specification. The `override` specification is like comment, but checked by the compiler. What do you not understand here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"override" is simply there so the implementor of a class can say "this method is supposed to override one from my base classes". If he does, then the compiler will provide an error if the method does not actually override a base class method -- which can happen if you mistype the name, or the base class changes later.

EDIT: Thus, it's a tool that helps with writing correct code; it's not meant to be a documentation keyword of some kind.

Comment: Ehhhh these features (`override`, `const`, etc.) that restrict when code can compile aren't so much for the writer of the code as other readers.  Yes, they are "documentation" keywords - if I'm reading code that can compile with the keyword `override` in it, I absolutely know it's overriding a base class method, with far more certainty than the `virtual` keyword with a comment above it saying `//overrides!`.

Comment: Your edit is the relevant part - but can you substantiate that claim? I'm inclined to say both you and @djechlin are partly right. Since the language doesn't (yet) let you perfectly expose ***only*** what's relevant to users, I'll wind up just using override everywhere it's applicable.

Comment: Readers of code are not users, they are maintainers.  Of course "override" can server a "typo check" feature as well but I'm still inclined to assert that maintainability is "the" purpose of such features.  Justifying this would involve taking all of my experience in software engineering, condensing it into intuition then digging through the annals of computer science and C language history looking for the right interview with Dennis Ritchie or some such original source, which I'm not inclined to do.

Comment: @djechlin Users are in the eye of the beholder. If you write libraries, your users are programmers.